# MySQL Sounds like to ignore 'The,a' etc

Tags: mysql

I have a table which includes names and each have a unique `itemcode` field, however I also have another table which we use as the *root* table for everything, this extra table is an extra I've recently added.

Because the names in my root table differ from the names in this new table, I need a *bridge* table, which I've created using a query which performs a `INSERT..SELECT` where the name in one table is equal to another. This is great, however it's limited my results because some names include `The` or `A` at the beginning so I'm missing them. So now I've changed my `a = b` query to a `SOUNDS LIKE` however that's only included names with differences at the end.

What I'm looking for is a way of ignoring a certain set of words such as:

- The
- A
- Be
- And

Etc and use the rest of the name? I can't do a 'LIKE %%' because that would capture too much.

Comment: remove {"the", "a", "be", "and"}, trim, toLower it, compare them.

Comment: `REPLACE` only allows you to do one word at a time, plus I don't want to remove **every** occurrence, just the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the words `The`, `A`, `Be` etc by using the `like` statement.  Ensure you have spaces on either side of the search terms so that it matches whole words, and not partial words.

```
SELECT * FROM namestable where names Like '% The %'
```

Comment: But what about the names which don't have `The` in them?

Comment: I was mearly pointing out that like can be used to pick out words.  The answer here is a generalisation, giving example of how `like` can be used to filter such results. In your case you want anything that is `not like '% The %'` and any other terms that you deem unfit.